# How to load CI controller function without refresh in view?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When i check some league, i want to load seasons from database what i have for that league.

I tried this code.

**test.php view**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var site_url = "<?php echo base_url('/system/getseasons/SC0'); ?>"; //SC0 is here as example, there will be selected league
            $("#season").load(site_url);
        });
    </script>
```

**System.php controller**

```
public function getseasons($div){
   $seasons = $this->sys_model->getseasonsforleague($div);
   $mode = '';
   foreach($seasons->result() as $season){
      if($season->Season != ''){
        $newseason = $this->season_filter($season->Season);
        if($mode == 'edit' and $system->bet_venue !== NULL){
        $season_arr = explode(";",$system->seasons);
          foreach($season_arr as $seas){
              if($season->Season == $seas){
                 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='season[]' checked='checked' value=". $season->Season .">" . $newseason . "</input><br>";              
              }
          }
          if($season->Season != $seas){
              echo "<input type='checkbox' name='season[]' value=". $season->Season .">" . 
              $newseason . "</input><br>";            

          }
        }
        else{
          echo "<input type='checkbox' name='season[]' value=". $season->Season .">" . $newseason . "</input><br>";     }
      }
   }
}
```

*NOTE: this controller 100% works because when i manually go to this link:
site.com/system/getseasons/SC0 i get all seasons for SC0 league.*

**and Sys_model.php model**

```
public function getseasonsforleague($div){
    $this->db->select('Season');
    $this->db->where('Div',$div);
    $this->db->group_by('Season');
    return $this->db->get('historic');
}
```

When i check browser **Console** i see **404** error:

> GET https://www.example.com/system/getseasons/SC0 404 (OK)send @
>   jquery.min.js:5m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:5m.fn.load @
>   jquery.min.js:5(anonymous function) @ test:11j @
>   jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready @
>   jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2

But one more time, this link works:

> https://www.example.com/system/getseasons/SC0

Also i tried this:

```
var site_url = "<?php echo base_url('/index.php/system/getseasons/SC0');
```

but again 404.

UPDATE: Network tab
[image: network]

Comment: Use AJAX to update view without refresh

Comment: @A.P. If you can give me some example, i have not experience in AJAX.

Comment: @A.P. isn't `$.load ` a jquery ajax function?

Comment: remove `index.php` and check once.

Comment: you could also try using relative path, by removing base_url() function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
` var site_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+'/system/getseasons/SC0';`
```

Comment: Again 404:

GET https://www.example.com/system/getseasons/SC0 404 (OK)send @ jquery.min.js:5m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:5m.fn.load @ jquery.min.js:5(anonymous function) @ test:11j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: base_url is right, but see this in console:

(anonymous function) @ test:11
On line 11 is this:
$("#season").load(site_url);
It looks like .load function won't works?

Comment: write body instead of site_url

Comment: sorry i don't understand you, what do you mean by 'write body'?

Comment: $("#season").load('body');

Comment: same
GET https://www.example.co/system/body 404 (OK)send @ jquery.min.js:5m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:5m.fn.load @ jquery.min.js:5(anonymous function) @ test:11j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var site_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+'system/getseasons/SC0/';
```

Comment: Same answer like @Mayank Vadiya but won't work. I tried this 'system/getseasons/SC0'; and this '/system/getseasons/SC0'; 404

Comment: nope 404 again:
GET https://www.example.co/system/getseasons/SC0/ 404 (OK)send @ jquery.min.js:5m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:5m.fn.load @ jquery.min.js:5
(anonymous function) @ test:11
j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: check screenshot in question up.

Comment: sees the error is from the server configuration or file permisons,you have 404 error on each page request

Comment: Hmm what cause this? I saw this when i change site to SSL.